# Как получить текст после символа # при приеме запроса через HttpListener

Tags: c#, .net

Я отправляю запрос авторизации через стороннюю библиотеку в дропбокс. После нажатия кнопки в браузере, дропбокс запрашивает по redirect_uri, который слушает моё приложение. Формат следующий

```
[REDIRECT_URI]#access_token=ABCDEFG&token_type=bearer&uid=12345&state=[STATE]
```

Я пользуюсь классом HttpListener, но после получения запроса свойство httpListener.Request.Url содержит адрес до решетки.

Я попробовал, он всегда так делает - показывает адрес до решетки.
Вопрос: как с этим бороться?

Comment: А вы уверены, что URI с решёткой не устанавливаются скриптом, а контент не подгружается через AJAX? Проверьте.

Comment: @VladD я пробовал вручную сам себя из браузера запрашивать с решеткой. Оно не приходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напрямую - никак. Браузер в принципе не отправляет часть после решетки - fragment - на сервер.

Косвенно - отдавать запросу этого uri промежуточную страницу. На странице скриптом вырезать часть uri после #, и отправлять ее на сервер еще одним запросом.